# Can't understand why my code not working (easy ui)

Tags: android

hello guys i have this function for focus :

```
fav[jj].setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public int kl = jj;
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                 log("last = "+last);
                     log("kkk = "+kl);  
                     saver ssss = new saver();
                 if(v.hasFocus())
                    {
                     if(kl+1 ==ssss.loadCount())
                     {
                         log("hjere");
                            delete.setEnabled(true);
                            btnUp.setEnabled(false);
                            btnDown.setEnabled(false);
                            btnGo.setEnabled(true);
                            btnDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.notactivedown);
                            btnUp.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowup);
                            log("here naxxx");
                     }
                    }
```

when i touched on my object fav[n] .. than this function must set button status to false. But this not work.. i can't understand because in logcat i see two lines : `log("hjere");` and `log("here naxxxx");` if i see ("log("here naxxx") ) than code must work ??

can any one please tell me why my code don't want work ? :(

Regards , Peter.

Comment: I think some `View`s are not focusable in touch mode.

Comment: but this view is focusable :(. just can't understand why can't setEnable(false) in focus mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an OnClickListener for that I think.

Comment: yep, in onClickListener it's work all.. but can't understand why in focuseListener this not work...

Comment: OnFocusListener registers focus, not click. A change of focus occurs, say, if you use a track ball to browse through screen components.